# How to move one content div into another without rendering again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to move my html content from one div into another BUT WITHOUT rendering it again!

When I use the jquery html() method it will be rendered fully again!

E.g.

```
<div id="1">
<script>console.log("test")</script>
</div>
<div id="2">
</div>

<script>
 $('#2').html($('#1').html())
</script>
```

will cause:

test
test

what I want is:

test

Comment: I think cloning the element does the trick. JQuery has a clone() method but it's javascript native. http://cha1tanya.com/2014/01/18/jquery-append-and-clone.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a combination of jQuery's [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) and [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) methods.

```
<div id="1">
    <script>console.log("test")</script>
</div>
<div id="2">
</div>

<script>
    $('#1').children().clone().appendTo('#2');
</script>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n92vs2py/) to demonstrate. Take a look at the console, and you should see that "test" is only logged once. If you want to move the elements from `#1` to `#2` rather than copy them, you can just remove `.clone()` from the chain.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $('#2').hide().html($('#1').html())
</script>
```